# Please help in integrating pnp4nagios with icinga-web

Tags: monitoring, icinga, nagios

Has anyone worked on integrating pnp4nagios with icinga-web?

My icinga-web version is 1.8.1

After installing icinga-web-pnp, I am having following files:

- pnp-host-extension.xml
- pnp-service-extension.xml

At this location:

```
/usr/share/icinga-web/app/modules/Cronks/data/xml/extensions
```

I am not seeing perfdata as column by default in console?

Am I missing something?

process_perf_data is also set to 1 in host object definition.

Comment: This problem is resolved now.

Answer (score 1):

After having found the expander icon, you can also rightclick on the graph icons and move them back to the grid - look here for some discussion on that feature with screenshots: https://dev.icinga.org/issues/3432

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the version of icinga-web you use in version 1.8 the icon linking to the pnp4nagios web section is hidden in between the lines so you need to click the icon:

"click to expand"

This will bring up the pnp4nagios extra buttons.